# getopts call function dont give any result

Tags: bash, function, getopts

Hello i trying to do a project from school, but i have a little problem, when i try to execute the function via getopts i don't get any result, im stuck right now.

Is there something wrong about how im calling a function in getopts, because if i try to display the help menu with -h works well, but trying to make the multiplication with -c don't give any result

```
    usage(){
    echo -e "Example Usage:"
    echo -e "myscript.sh [-h] [-n1] [-n2] [-c]"       
    exit 0
}

    calculator(){
    echo "$num1*$num2"
    mul=$(( $num1*$num2 ))
    echo Result $mul
    exit 0
}

while getopts ":n1:n2:c:h" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        n1)
            num1=${OPTARG}
            ;;      
        n2)
            num2=${OPTARG}
            ;;  
        c)
            calculator
            ;;  
        h)
            usage
            ;;
        *)
            #usage
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: @ufopilot thanks now works, can you explain me please why changing n1 and n2 and join c with h do the work?

Comment: look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

> getopts parses short options, which are a single dash ("-") and a
> letter or digit. Examples of short options are -2, -d, and -D. It can
> also parse short options in combination, for instance -2dD.

Change n1 and n2 to one letter x, y.

> If the option is expecting an argument, getopts gets that argument,
> and places it in $OPTARG. If an expected argument is not found, the
> variable optname is set to a colon (":"). Getopts then increments the
> positional index, $OPTIND, that indicates the next option to be
> processed.

remove ":" after c. --> while getopts "x:y:ch" o; do ...
c is not expecting an argument

```
usage(){
        echo -e "Example Usage:"
        echo -e "myscript.sh [-h] [-x] [-y] [-c]"
        exit 0
    }

calculator(){
    echo "$num1*$num2"
    mul=$(( $num1*$num2 ))
    echo Result $mul
    exit 0
}

while getopts "x:y:ch" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        x)
            num1=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        y)
            num2=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        c)
            calculator
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            ;;
        *)
            #usage
            ;;
    esac
done


./myscript.sh -x 3 -y 4 -c
3*4
Result 12
```

If you wan't use long options:

```
optspec="x:y:ch-:"
while getopts "$optspec" optchar; do
    case "${optchar}" in
        -)
            case "${OPTARG}" in
                n1) num1="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ));;
                n2) num2="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ));;
                n1=*) num1=${OPTARG#*=};;
                n2=*) num2=${OPTARG#*=};;
                *)
                    if [ "$OPTERR" = 1 ] && [ "${optspec:0:1}" != ":" ]; then
                       usage
                    fi
                    ;;
            esac;;
        h) usage;;
        c) calculator;;
        x) num1=${OPTARG};;
        y) num2=${OPTARG};;
        *)
            if [ "$OPTERR" != 1 ] || [ "${optspec:0:1}" = ":" ]; then
                echo "Non-option argument: '-${OPTARG}'" >&2
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done



./myscript.sh --n1 3 -n2 4 -c
 or 
 ./myscript.sh --n1=3 -n2=4 -c
 3*4
 Result 12
```